# WP Upload Image Through Ajax Response Issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, jquery-file-upload

I am facing an issue when I am trying to upload the image through WP ajax from front side. I can see the Ajax triggering fine. I can successfully upload the image to the server as well. But when I try to read the response, it does not do anything.

Here is my Ajax request.

```
 jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     cache: false,
     url: testing.ajax_url,
     data: form_data,
     success: function (res) {
         if ("success" == res.response) {
            alert("Yeah!");
         } else {
            alert("Hmm");
         }
     }
});
```

I can see the response in the network area as well like {"response":"success"} this, but not able to access it.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `res = JSON.parse(res)` right before your if statement?

Comment: Yes, I did try that as well. But no success.